# Adobe AIR expansion files

Tags: air, adobe, apk, expansion, apk-expansion-files

I have an app, a game made in Adobe Air. The app has more than 50 MB. I would like to know how to split my app using expansion files, so i can put it on the store. And if I split it, what does that mean for me? The game basically has a lot of bitmaps, and i already tried everything possible to make the size as low as it can be.

Answer (score 0):

You should see the [Google Play document](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/google/play/expansion-files.html).
In Air i think you should use [ANE](http://pol2095.free.fr/Air_APKExpansionFiles).
You can split your code with two part.One is the assest ,Another is the code .
You can just change the path to load the resource.